# Combining forecasts into a data frame in R and then exporting into excel

Tags: r, excel, forecasting

I'm currently running multiple `auto.arima()` forecasts in R to generate a series of point forecasts with confidence intervals that I'd like to be able to pull directly into excel. A sample of the script I've currently been using below is shown for a portion of my data.

```
require(forecast)


# Customer GM ARIMA Forecasts (1 Quarter Ahead)

F1 <- read.csv("C:/datapath/Desktop/dataname.csv")

F1 <- ts(F1, frequency = 12, start = c(2014, 1), end = c(2015, 12))

Coonan <- F1[,3]
Gallo  <- F1[,4]
Kempton<- F1[,5]
Moore  <- F1[,6]
Nekic  <- F1[,7]


fit.Coonan  <- auto.arima(Coonan, stepwise = FALSE)
fc.Coonan   <- forecast(fit.Coonan, h=3, level = c(20, 40, 80))

fit.Gallo   <- auto.arima(Gallo, stepwise = FALSE)
fc.Gallo    <- forecast(fit.Gallo, h=3, level = c(20, 40, 80))

fit.Kempton <- auto.arima(Kempton, stepwise = FALSE)
fc.Kempton  <- forecast(fit.Kempton, h=3, level = c(20, 40, 80))

fit.Kempton <- auto.arima(Kempton, stepwise = FALSE)
fc.Kempton  <- forecast(fit.Kempton, h=3, level = c(20, 40, 80))

fit.Moore   <- auto.arima(Moore, stepwise = FALSE)
fc.Moore    <- forecast(fit.Moore, h=3, level = c(20, 40, 80))

fit.Nekic   <- auto.arima(Nekic, stepwise = FALSE)
fc.Nekic    <- forecast(fit.Nekic, h=3, level = c(20, 40, 80))



# Save to clipboard to copy and paste into excel

write.excel <- function(x,row.names=TRUE,col.names=TRUE,...) {
  write.table(x,"clipboard",sep="\t",row.names=row.names,col.names=col.names,...)
}

write.excel(fc.Coonan)   # Then can paste Coonan Forecasts Directly into excel
```

After pasting my result into excel I get a table that looks like this this (I'd like to shift over column names, but that's not a big problem right now).
[image]

As currently written I need to manually change the name of the model in the bottom function, run the function (in order to save the results to the clipboard), and then copy and paste the results into excel. This process has become very time consuming and I'm wondering if there's a simple way to combine my series of point forecasts and confidence intervals into one data frame that I can then export all at once into excel.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Yes, there are several packages that can write a dataframe to excel. I found `xlsx` very easy to learn, but it is not very fast in reading/writing. But as your dataframes are very small, that is probably not a problem.

Comment: Is writing as csv and explore that in excel an option? Can be done easily with write.csv().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one using `openxlsx` which I find to be preferable to any of the other packages because it uses C++ instead of Java which often runs out of memory writing even small sheets.

You may need to set the path to `zip` though if you get the error:

> Error: zipping up workbook failed. Please make sure Rtools is installed or a zip application is available to R.
>            Try installr::install.rtools() on Windows.

```
library(forecast)
library(openxlsx)
Sys.setenv(R_ZIPCMD = "C:/RBuildTools/3.1/bin/zip")

# create dummy data
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
build <- data.table()
F1 <- build[, lapply(seq(7), function(x) runif(24))]

F1 <- ts(F1, frequency = 12, start = c(2014, 1), end = c(2015, 12))

Coonan <- F1[,3]
Gallo  <- F1[,4]
Kempton<- F1[,5]
Moore  <- F1[,6]
Nekic  <- F1[,7]

results <- list()

fit.Coonan  <- auto.arima(Coonan, stepwise = FALSE)
results[["Coonan"]] <- forecast(fit.Coonan, h=3, level = c(20, 40, 80))

fit.Gallo   <- auto.arima(Gallo, stepwise = FALSE)
results[["Gallo"]] <- forecast(fit.Gallo, h=3, level = c(20, 40, 80))

fit.Kempton <- auto.arima(Kempton, stepwise = FALSE)
results[["Kempton"]] <- forecast(fit.Kempton, h=3, level = c(20, 40, 80))

fit.Moore   <- auto.arima(Moore, stepwise = FALSE)
results[["Moore"]] <- forecast(fit.Moore, h=3, level = c(20, 40, 80))

fit.Nekic   <- auto.arima(Nekic, stepwise = FALSE)
results[["Nekic"]] <- forecast(fit.Nekic, h=3, level = c(20, 40, 80))

results_together <- do.call(rbind,lapply(names(results),function(x){
  transform(as.data.frame(results[[x]]), Name = x)
}))

wb <- createWorkbook()

addWorksheet(wb, "Forecasts")
writeData(wb, "Forecasts", results_together, rowNames = TRUE)
saveWorkbook(wb, "Forcasts.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Results in this:

[image]

You can also put each result on its own tab (with or without adding the `Name` column):

```
wb <- createWorkbook()

for (nm in names(results)){
  addWorksheet(wb, nm)
  writeData(wb, nm, results[[nm]], rowNames = TRUE)
}

saveWorkbook(wb, "Forcasts.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Resulting in:

[image]

Comment: I'm getting the following error `Rtools’ is not available (for R version 3.2.3)` , but I can still use the same function I was using originally to paste the data frame into excel through the clipboard. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

mlegge,

This is a brilliant solution. I came across issues with RTools and came across a workaround  using write.csv:

write.csv(results_together, file="results_together.csv")

-phos