# Creating a data frame in R from forecasts to use it for predict

Tags: r, forecast

I need your help in creating a data frame in R which contains separate columns of each forecasted variable. This "new data" will be used for predict line after regression.

The classical example online is as follows:

```
data=read.csv("some_path", header=TRUE)

fit<- with(data, lm(y1 ~x1))
pred<-predict.lm(fit, newdata=data.frame("x1"=some_number))
```

The model has three steps:

1. Perform simple auto.arima forecasts for independent variables x1...xn.

```
fit_x1<- auto.arima(x1, stepwise = FALSE)

for_x1<-forecast(fit_x1, h=10)

...

fit_xn<- auto.arima(xn, stepwise = FALSE)

for_xn<-forecast(fit_xn, h=10)
```

After forecasting I need to create a data frame which contains each forecasted variable (x1...xn). Moreover, the "new data" should contain the columns with the exact names of X's used later in the regression. In these columns only the values of point forecasts should be saved, without Hi and Lo values.

2. Run regression between y1 and x1...xn.

```
fit<- lm(formula=log(y1)~log(x1)+log(x2)+...+log(xn), data=data)

summary(fit)
```

3. Perform a prediction using the results from "fit" and "new data" from step 1.

```
pred<- predict.lm(fit, newdata)
```

There is a very interesting post on this issue: [Combining forecasts into a data frame in R and then exporting into excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34659586/combining-forecasts-into-a-data-frame-in-r-and-then-exporting-into-excel)
However, in that particular case a new data frame is created from forecasts that produces only one column where forecasts from different x's are combined.

Can this three step procedure work in case of panel data time series?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the following code should help you to create a `newdata` `data.frame`.

## Required libraries to re preduce.

```
# library(dplyr)
# library(stats)
# library(forecast)
```

## With the following code I will create an example data with 5 time series:

```
set.seed(123)

dta <- ts(dplyr::tibble(
  AA = arima.sim(list(order=c(1,0,0), ar=.5), n=100, mean = 12), 
  AB = arima.sim(list(order=c(1,0,0), ar=.5), n=100, mean = 12), 
  AC = arima.sim(list(order=c(1,0,0), ar=.5), n=100, mean = 11), 
  BA = arima.sim(list(order=c(1,0,0), ar=.5), n=100, mean = 10), 
  BB = arima.sim(list(order=c(1,0,0), ar=.5), n=100, mean = 14)
), start = c(2013, 1), frequency = 12)

head(dta)
tail(dta)
```

## Now we will do the batch forecasting and create one new data `data.frame`/`matrix`.

```
nseries <- ncol(dta)
h <- 12 # forecast horizon

newdata <- matrix(nrow = h, ncol = nseries) # empty newdata matrix

for (i in seq_len(nseries)) {
  
  newdata[,i] <- forecast::forecast(forecast::auto.arima(dta[,i]), h = h)$mean
}

colnames(newdata) <- colnames(dta)

head(newdata)
```

I hope I understood the problem correctly.

Comment: Many thanks for replying. My problem is to transform the original data set into ts on monthly basis. I manage to transform in ts using your method but after running the auto.arima I get this error:```Error: Assigned data `forecast::forecast(forecast::auto.arima(dta[, i]), h = h)$mean` must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 276 rows.
x Assigned data has 12 rows.
i Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.```

Comment: `new_data[,i] <- forecast::forecast(forecast::auto.arima(dta[, i]), h = h)$mean`

Comment: Can we chat? I have some details to ask. Many thanks for your reply.

Comment: @Marian sure!                               .